# What features will be restricted for dropbox free users after March 15, 2017?

Tags: dropbox

Actual News is here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

I didn't understand the news.

I contacted them but they are asking me to submit ticket. I submitted ticket 10 days back, still no reply.

After March 15, will I be able to use the share option which is located beside a file?

Please help me. I am dependent on Dropbox.

I daily share files in Dropbox. I feel Dropbox is more comfortable than Google Drive or other cloud services.

I am a free user of Dropbox.

Comment: You might want to look at https://spideroak.com/ which is similar, but encrypted end to end (if you lose your password, they cannot help you).  I have been happy with the free version for years and have 18gB free storage from friends accepting my recommendation,

Answer (score 4):

For free users, "the Public folder will be converted into a standard Dropbox folder that’s private to your account."
If anyone you've shared a link with previously clicks that link after March 15, they will receive an error page. You will have to reshare files again.

I can't imagine they are removing the share button next to the file or folder you want to share, but here's their suggestion on resharing your content.
https://www.dropbox.com/help/274

Answer (score 3):

The Public folder is a special folder (there's only one of it in the whole Dropbox. It's hard-coded) where if you put anything in you **automatically** get a link from which anybody around the web can view that file, **without you having to explicitly click on the share button**.

As is clearly stated on the page:

> Dropbox accounts created after October 4, 2012, will not have a Public folder. Don't worry. You can quickly share anything with friends and colleagues—even if they don’t have Dropbox—by using a shared link.

So don't worry. It would be absolutely ridiculous to remove normal sharing function.

The removing of the Public folder is not restricted to free users. It's just that Dropbox decided to drop this functionality, for everybody.

I don't think there's anything that's very hard to understand about that statement. It's very clear. Maybe you got confused since you created your account after October 4, 2012 and don't know what the Public folder is.